# how do i stop an rdlc tablix row from page breaking in the middle

Tags: pagination, rdlc, ssrs-tablix, localreport

i have a tablix where the row consists of two columns.  inside each column there is a textbox with two paragraphs.  what i want to generate is:

the row height is 1/2 inch.  the textbox is bottom aligned.  the output should be:

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___     __*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____
   name                                      date

and this is repeated for each name in the datatable.  the problem that i am beating my head against the wall over is that the underline will sometimes show up at the bottom of the page and the next line with the words name and date will show up at the top of the next page.

what is the setting that will guarrantee that the underline and the text below it will never break over a page

Answer (score 0):

Check the KeepTogether setting first. If that doesn't help, place them both in a rectangle together. Make sure you drag them onto the rectangle for them to be associated with it.